# Formula for sum of this infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

What is the formula for the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-p)(p^n)$ for $p \in (1/2, 1)$? Just from playing around on WolframAlpha it seems like it's something like $-\frac{1}{ax-b}$ if $p = a/b$ but what if p is just some decimal? And how would I prove the formula? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a geometric series

Comment: It  is a geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n(1-p)(p^n)=(1-p)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(xp)^n$

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like it would be $\frac{1-p}{1-xp}$.

Comment: Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series